# iOS Sprite-Kit run device EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, sprite-kit, game-engine

I ran into the following problem: When I simulate my App with the iPhone 4" mode, then the app runs fine. But when I try to simulate it with the 4" 64-bit mode, then I get the following error:
(I reckon a screenshot is better, because it provides more information..?)
http://www11.pic-upload.de/30.06.14/wco1pqu19h5n.png

But when I try to emulate it on my actual iPhone 5, then an error occurs as follows.
http://www11.pic-upload.de/30.06.14/xe3wj5r3zid.png

All I wanted is to implement some sort of Joystick. Because "JC Input" just didn´t work (could´t implement it..), I opted for "Sneaky Narwhale", which (apparently) still is troublesome for me...

Can anyone help me with my EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue? I would like to run it on my device.
I came across something with ZombieEnabling when looking through other posts, but I seem to not get any further =/

Comment: Are you initializing your Joystick class before adding it as a child?

Answer (score 0):

Your joystick property is declared as:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) ..
```

where assign under ARC is the equivalent of __unsafe_unretained. In other words the variable assigned to that property is not retained, ARC will find that there is no more strong reference to the variable left, sometimes just the next line or two after having initialized it, but the property keeps a reference to the now-dangling pointer which crashes the next time it is used.

Remove ALL 'assign' keywords in properties because you shouldn't use them for objc object references lest you will run into the same issue again elsewhere. This will make a property default to 'strong' references. Where strong is not necessary or undesirable, use weak instead but not assign.